# Cluster still imbalanced after restore and rebalances

Tags: couchbase

I ran a cbbackup of a single bucket, 4 node, 2.2.0 community edition (build-837) cluster that was fairly imbalanced (718k, 565k, 383k, 383k items in each node), created a new 3 node cluster (same build), and ran cbrestore. The new cluster also came up imbalanced (1035k, 515k, 516k items in each node). In order to distribute the keys evenly, we added a node and ran rebalance, but a significant imbalance remained akin to the distribution in the old cluster. We removed the new node and rebalanced, and the item distribution went back to what it was. We actually did this twice just to see if it would make a difference. All rebalances completed successfully. Note that the replica distributions are similarly skewed where one node has about twice the number of items as the others.

Any ideas about how to correct the skew of data across servers? Any ideas of why it would skew in the first place? Is there risk that if one node goes down, there will be a loss of data?

Comment: going to need some more information:
* Is this a couchbase bucket (I assume it is)?
* How many replicas do you have?
* How many vbuckets does each node have? (You can get that from the UI under vbucket resources or using this command: `/opt/couchbase/bin/cbstats localhost:11210 vbucket -b beer-sample | grep -c active`)

Comment: Yes, it is a couchbase bucket.  1 replica.  1024 total vbuckets. 342, 341, and 341 vbuckets on each node.  same numbers for the replica as well.  It seems like the distribution hash is skewed.

Comment: The hashing function is client side. What was the original client you used to write the data into couchbase before the backup and restore?

Comment: We use the moxi client.  Per the manifest.txt file, it looks to be 1.7.0 which might be the issue since it's so old.

Comment: The app uses php.  I believe they are using libmemcached to connect to the moxi.  Still trying to understand all the pieces to the puzzle.